# How to enable a TextBox datepicker inside ContentPlaceHolder DetailsView1 TemplateField EditItemTemplate ASPX VB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

From a javascript novice, so please bear with me...

Setup: master page with 3 ContentPlaceHolders ("head" inside 'head' tag, "ContentPlaceHolder1" and "ContentPlaceHolder2" in 'body'-'form' tag).

On Content page, Content1 in "head" adds script for jquery, Content2 in "ContentPlaceHolder1" contains H1 text only.
Content3 in "ContentPlaceHolder2" contains a GridView and DetailsView with associated DataSources.

My problem is in the DetailsView1, with enabled the Edit functionality thus shows in its 'DetailsView'-'Field'-'TemplateField'-'EditItemTemplate' a Texbox like:
asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnPreRender="TextBox2_PreRender"

In TextBox2_PreRender I want to try and add a script to enable datepicker functionality, as I need to select a Month and Year only.

Problem: for some reason TextBox2 cannot be accessed programmatically in code behind, however using structure as per above allows 'sender' to be the TextBox thus to access it programmatically, any solution to this is welcomed greatly.

I can add a script to run when the TextBox2 is clicked using "onclick", no problem so far ensuring this structure triggers the script to execute.

Main Problem: How do I instead of a confirm add the capability to have a datepicker which I can then format appropriately?

Markup for the PreRender reads:

```
Protected Sub TextBox2_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim tb as TextBox = sender
Dim script as String
script = "function addCal(){return confirm('ok')}"
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "TextBox2", script, True)
tb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "addCal()")
End Sub
```

I have looked at this sample [Month and Year Picker](http://jsfiddle.net/tmnasim/JLydp/) but am unsure how to implement it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, it should be as simple as setting the ClientIDMode of the text box to 'Static'.  If you look at how ASP.NET controls render, they have funny ID's that are often unpredictable.  Setting the ClientIDMode to static means that they render with the ID that you have specified, and with nothing prefixed to that.

Comment: Having changed the ClientIDMode to Static, I now get a message advising "Unhanded exception... 0x800a01b6 Javascript runtime error; Object doesn't support property or method 'date picker' For completeness, the function reads addCal(){("TextBox2").datepicker()};

Comment: If I change the TextBox to an input control the datepicker works fine, just not on the TextBox...

Comment: If you're still stuck with it, could you please post some more of the relevant code.  Some of the ASP.NET code could be useful, along with some of the JavaScript you are using.  Your PreRender method looks fine to me, although I don't program in VB.NET so I can't be 100% sure on that.